# Reshaping a n,m,k matrix to a n*m k

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I need to reshape a matrix A to B, sample:

A size = [n m k]
B size = [n*m k]

What is the fastest way to set B lines with A values?

Comment: Have you tried `reshape`?

Comment: I'm not used to matlab, thanks to @nirvana-msu I did, as you can see on his answer.

Comment: Ohh I got a -1, hater detected. This is a valid question, can be useful for matlab newbies like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A = randn(2,3,4);
B = reshape(A, [], size(A,3));

>> size(B)
ans =
     6     4
```